# 0.0 is not a valid timestamp

Tags: timestamp

Добрый день!
Есть клиентская программа, которая ведет себя странно на разных машинах - а именно выдает такую ошибку

```
0.0 is not a valid timestamp
```

Причем совершенно нестабильно - под одними и теми же учетными данными, но на разных машинах ошибка на одной есть, на другой - нет.
Можно узнать внятную причину появления ошибки? Раз она зависит от машины.

Comment: Вот не понимаю - при чём тут SQL, если это проблема клиентской программы? Вы бы переформулировали вопрос, чтобы эта связь стала очевидной...

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от настроек клиентской программы. Сравните NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT на разных машинах.

Answer (score 0):

А проверь-ка десятичный разделитель на компах - скорее всего на части из них точка (где работает), а на части - запятая (где не работает).

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка возникает при неявном преобразовании строчного литерала в `timestamp`. Без кода вряд ли возможно локализовать причину. Чтобы исключить такое преобразование, можно всюду, где ожидается `timestamp` как параметр воспользоваться его литералом.
Формат литерала не зависит ни от каких настроек:

```
timestamp '2019-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```